# MakeFile error in Unix

Tags: c++, linux, unix, makefile

I am having an issue with executing a makefile. I am trying to make a 'guess' file from yesno.cpp and guess.cpp. I am to create a yesnno.o file and guess.o file from the before mentioned files. My code is as follows:

```
g++ -c -DDEBUG yesno.cpp
g++ -c -DDEBUG guess.cpp
```

I am then supposed to link these 2 .o files and create an executable program named guess. My code is as follows:

```
g++ -o guess guess.o yesno.o
```

This creates the guess file with the following files in my directory:

```
guess guess.cpp guess.o yesno.cpp yesno.h yesno.o
```

All seems fine until I try to submit this, but I keep getting an error saying:

```
"make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

Your makefile does not build 'guess' when invoked"
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help!

Comment: What does your Makefile contain? Do you even have a Makefile? Or are you trying to literally run your Makefile? Did you try: `make` ?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is asking a question about your `Makefile` but without showing a single line of your `Makefile`, expecting everyone to guess what's in it, I suppose.

Comment: I guess I do not have a makefile. I thought the makefile WAS the guess file that's created from guess.o and yesno.o. It says I am supposed to create a makefile that will compile yesno.cpp and guess.cpp to produce files guess.o and yesno.o.

Comment: No, that's not what a makefile is.

Comment: How would you create a makefile from that then?

Comment: You know how to build `guess` (with the three commands above). Make is a tool that lets you automate certain tasks -- such as building files -- by means of a script which Make reads, called a makefile. Learning to write makefiles takes some time and effort.

Comment: I have been using google for the past 2 days and still cannot understand what I am doing wrong, so I was told to come to this community for help.

Comment: everyone should use cmake, unless if one is not guru.

Comment: The question is unrelated to Emacs, AFAICT. I removed that tag.

Answer (score 1):

A makefile is a file used by the program `make` to build your project.  Try creating a file in your directory called `Makefile` or `makefile` with the following content.

```
CXX = g++

.PHONY: all

.SECONDARY:

all: guess

guess: guess.o yesno.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp yesno.h
    $(CXX) -c -DDEBUG $<
```

To build your project, run `make`.  You can run, e.g., `make -j2` to run up to 2 jobs in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused on the makefile. You actually have to create a makefile in the directory that you are in.

After the makefile is created, you need to enter the parameters inside of the makefile.

Here is an EXCELLENT video that was pointed out to me about makefiles:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aw9wHbFTnAQ

Thanks for the help!

Comment: By "in the directory that you are in", I guess you mean "in the directory that Make uses" - that's the working directory of the `make` process, unless it's told different by use of the `-C` option (GNU Make).

Answer (score 0):

Make has default rules to create object files from C++ source, and to link object files.  This means that a complete Makefile is as simple as:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -DDEBUG

guess: LINK.o = $(LINK.cc)
guess: guess.o yesno.o

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
```

Notes:

- I've included `-Wall` that you forgot from your compilation command; `-Wextra` can spot further problems with your code, and I recommend it.
- The `LINK` line ensures that your program is linked as C++, not C (different standard libraries).
- `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` should be in every Makefile you write: it prevents half-compiled object code hanging around if the build is interrupted.
- I'm assuming GNU Make, since the target is [linux](/questions/tagged/linux).